# AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF.LoadFile changes?

Tags: acrobat, axacropdf

I have made a Windows client application where I use the AxAcroPDF control
to display a pdf-file on a form.

It seems to me that after I have upgraded my Acrobat reader from version 8 to version 9 the LoadFile method returns true when the file is opened correctly, where version 8 returned false. Is this a correct observation?

Best Regards,
Krimson

Answer (score 3):

I realize this thread is a little old, but I made the same observation and I had to change my code for the 9.0 version.

Comment: Did you find any way to test which version of the Acrobat Reader is installed?

Answer (score 0):

Not at all! The version of Acrobat doesn't influence in the way AxAcroPDF control works. You must debug to see what happens

Answer (score 0):

LoadFile returns -1 on success, 0 on failure. This can be found in the [documentation for Acrobat 9](http://livedocs.adobe.com/acrobat_sdk/9.1/Acrobat9_1_HTMLHelp/IAC_API_OLE_Objects.103.175.html). I can't find the online reference for version 8, but I downloaded it from Adobe and it is the same. What programming language are you using? Have you got some sample code?

Comment: I'm using c#. I've created a Windows Forms UserControl, where the AxAcroPDFLib.AxAcroPDF control is hosted. This Windows Forms UserControl is used within a WindowsFormsHost in a WPF application.
Which part do you want to see sample code from?

Comment: Where the mystery return code is obtained - the call and the result, and the difference between version 8 and 9.